# Compile .JAV file?

Tags: java, windows, javac

If I have for instance `TestClass.java` in windows it's shortname will be  `TESTCL~1.JAV` *(If 8.3 notation is enabled on windows machine all files will have two names - it's real name and one short name for compatibility with older windows versions. Shortnames have maximum 8 letters name and 3 letters extension).*

Java is aware of that.Or at least seems to be.After the java installation there appears `.jav` extension description in the registry:

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.jav`

with the same persistent handler as `.java` file:

```
{5e941d80-bf96-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}
```

(it's the handler for plain text)

When I try to pass to the `javac` a java file with its short name I receive the following error:

```
javac: invalid flag: TESTCL~1.JAV
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

I.e. does not find file at all.

Is it possible to compile a file with `.jav` extension or using java file shortname?

Or the installed extension description is a long forgotten and not-anymore-working backward compatibility relic?

Comment: Show us the command line.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that in 2015? The short names are completely obsolete nowadays

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  - the right question is not `WHY?` but `WHY NOT?` :-). At the moment is just a curiosity , but I think eventually could use it.

Comment: @Kayaman - the command line is just `javac TESTCL~1.JAV` where `TESTCL~1.JAV` is the short name of the existing `TestClass.java` file.With no packages inside.

Answer (score 1):

The persistent handler `{5e941d80-bf96-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}` is simply the “Plain Text persistent handler” and in no way related to Java. When I search my machine I find this handler also installed for `.asc`, `.asm`, `.bas`, `.js` and lots of other I haven’t installed a specific development tool for. So obviously, there are a lot of pre-installed file-types marked as “can be handled like plain text” which might be used by the search engine. So I assume that the registry entry for `.jav` wasn’t actually created by the JDK, but to finally prove this, a computer without an installed JDK is required which I don’t have.